# Excel VBA QueryTable properties with errors

Tags: vba, excel

On my Excel 2003 VBA a standard QueryTable returns me a

> < Application-defined or object-defined error >

message as value for 5 properties, when I put it in the Watch-window. They are:

> - TextFileColumnDataTypes
> - TextFileDecimalSeparator
> - TextFileFixedColumnWidths
> - TextFileThousandsSeparator
> - TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers

I'm trying to set decimal and thousands properties, since the data I'm trying to retrieve comes from a foreing country.

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround for this?

---

To clarify the problem:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand this question. Showing more code might be helpful.

Comment: Is your data source a text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a solution for the properties problem, I used a simple workaround to solve the decimals and thousands problem by running this trivial piece of code right before refreshing the query:

```
With Application
    .DecimalSeparator = ","
    .ThousandsSeparator = "."
    .UseSystemSeparators = False
End With
```

And after refreshed, I run this to go back to my original american standard:

```
With Application
    .DecimalSeparator = "."
    .ThousandsSeparator = ","
    .UseSystemSeparators = False
End With
```

Anyway, thank you guys who tried to help... I guess this issue is particular to my Excel version.